# How can I find out which add-on is sending a message to the developer log?

Tags: add-on, error, developer-log

I'm working on a site that has a lot of add-ons, some probably redundant now. It is a very long term development project.

Since a recent EE update one of these add-ons is sending an error message to the developer log.

```
A third-party add-on is calling $this->load->library('security'), which is deprecated as the CI_Security class has been moved to Core, so it is always loaded.
```

This is great, but which add-on is it? How can I find out and is there a way to get the log to show slightly more useful information?

Comment: Did you try to search in all your code for $this->EE->load->library('security') ? It is generally how we resolve this. But I admit that if more info were given in the Dev log, that would be easier!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This came up [on Stack Overflow recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238144/what-add-ons-are-creating-messages-in-expressionengine-dev-log) and prompted a semi-official response:

> 1. This message will likely be removed in a future release. It's causing too much confusion than help and isn't entirely necessary. Yes it would be helpful for the developer log to let you know which addon is causing the problem, but the logistics of parsing backtraces to find that information proves to be difficult. Which brings us on to message #2:
> 2. As GDmac said, it's best to search your project for any calls to login_form() in the CP controller. Normally a file and line number would be provided in this kind of message, but as I said, parsing backtrace info doesn't always work.
>
> We'll continue to try to make this better. The deprecation warnings have been working great for the most part, but occasionally messages like these pop up it can be difficult to know what to do about them.