# Any idea on how to debugg this "Developer log" alert message?

Tags: developer-log

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out which add-on is sending a message to the developer log?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-can-i-find-out-which-add-on-is-sending-a-message-to-the-developer-log)

I have this message in my Developer log about some Add-on using "login_form()" function. When I search through all my Add-ons this function is nowhere to be seen :)

Any ideas how I remove this message? Keeps popin' up every 2-3 day.

Also it's complaining on "row 0"? :)

Thanks all!

Here's a screenshot of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPEuO.jpg

Comment: Got this from time to time as well. Likewise, no call to login_form() function anywhere

Answer (score 0):

This error is an absolute pain, debugging it is not easy at least in my experience. What addons do you have running, that maybe a better way to tackle this. In particular we are interested in anything that hasn't had an update in the last 12 months or so.

Comment: The site has these add-ons installed:

catimg
channel_images
ifelse
low_reorder
low_seg2cat
low_variables
matrix
playa
safecracker_file
seo_lite
sitemap
system_messages
tunchhtml
wygwam

I don't see any using the login_form() function(?)

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in EE 2x with the addon - Backup - Thomas Myer (worked fine in EE 1x) and simply switched to Backup Pro.

```
2 Reviews
Rating - 3.388 Votes
23 Favs
```